# Generate unix timestamp using xpath functions , what is wrong with this xslt script?

Tags: xslt, xpath

I am trying to generate timestamp but its giving me a floating number :

```
 <xsl:variable name="timestamp"  select="seconds-from-dateTime(current-dateTime())-seconds-from-dateTime(xs:dateTime('1970-01-01T00:00:00'))"/>
```

output sth like this: `40.638`

I am using functions describe [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From that page you linked to:

> > Returns a decimal that represents the seconds component in the localized value of the argument

The second value has 0 in its seconds component, and the first value has a value in the range [0, 60) in its seconds component, so the result will always be between 0 and 60.  Have you tried this:

```
<xsl:variable name="duration" 
      select="current-dateTime() - xs:dateTime('1970-01-01T00:00:00')" />
<xsl:variable name="timestamp"
              select="floor(days-from-duration($duration) * 3600 * 24 + 
                      hours-from-duration($duration) * 3600 + 
                      minutes-from-duration($duration) * 60 + 
                      seconds-from-duration($duration))" />
```

Comment: saxon says : `Unknown system function subtract-dateTimes()`. By the way you are right I was using wrong type of function

Comment: since subtract-dateTimes() gives me error I simply subtract e.g `current-dateTime()-xs:dateTime('1970-01-01T00:00:00')`  the output is sth in floating point : `1359568531.244` how we can avoid this ?

Comment: If all you want to do is remove the fractional part, you can just do `floor(current-dateTime()-xs:dateTime('1970-01-01T00:00:00'))`.  Is that what you're looking for?